# php check if mysql query will run

Tags: php, mysql

I have a webapp that lets you run querys from a DB using a simple textarea in a form. I have one problem:

I need to check the query memory consumption before it runs (so it won't crash my server).

Is there a way using PHP or MySQL to do that?

For example, i have 3 tables:

**News** (idNews,created,idMedio,state)
**NewsAreaMain** (idNewsAreaMain,idNews,idAreaMain)
**AreaMain** (idAreaMain)

and someone tried the following query that actually crashed the server:

```
SELECT DISTINCT News.* 
FROM NewsAreaMain, News 
WHERE 
    (
        (
            NewsAreaMain.idNews=News.idNews 
            AND News.idNews IN 
                (
                    SELECT DISTINCT News.idNews 
                    FROM News, NewsAreaMain 
                    WHERE NewsAreaMain.idNews=News.idNews 
                    AND NewsAreaMain.idAreaMain="1"
                 )
        ) 
    AND idMedio="5" 
    OR ( idMedio="6" )
    )
AND News.state=1 
ORDER BY created DESC 
LIMIT 0, 20;
```

Comment: Not that I know of. Make sure you trust your users to modify your database.

Comment: You want to allow execution of arbitrary user-input queries?  That doesn't sound like a great idea.

Comment: That sounds a bit scary, are you cleaning and restricting the user queries in any way... or allowing them to enter free text sql?

Comment: I know it's not a great idea, but the client wants something like that. I've already used a try/catch for possible errors, but yesterday a user made a query that crashed the server (in terms of memory usage).

Comment: Being restrictive with the user permissions on the user that executes the queries can help reduce security concerns, i.e. by giving SELECT permission only - will just restrict what can be run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know of. If there were one, I'm sure all the shared hosting sites out there would use it and block queries that are too intensive rather than using such a dirty method as killing queries that run too long.

That would probably be your only option. Have a process that periodically checked the first entry in `SHOW PROCESSLIST`, and if "Time" is above a certain value (it's in seconds, so 10 would probably be an ok, if tight, value. Anything above 60 is asking for trouble), kill it with `KILL QUERY #####` (using the relevant ID number returned as part of `SHOW PROCESSLIST`).

Answer (score 0):

No mysql query should crash the server. Mysql is quite good with that.
It seems it's not a query but some your code actually crashes the server.
If you care to provide more details on "crashing server", I am sure there will be a solution.

Comment: Here's what happened:

BD:
News (idNews)
NewsAreaMain (idNewsAreaMain,idNews,idAreaMain)
AreaMain (idAreaMain)

QUERY:
SELECT DISTINCT News.* 
FROM NewsAreaMain, News 
WHERE 
 (
     (
         NewsAreaMain.idNews=News.idNews 
            AND News.idNews IN 
             (
                 SELECT DISTINCT News.idNews 
                    FROM News, NewsAreaMain 
                    WHERE NewsAreaMain.idNews=News.idNews 
                    AND NewsAreaMain.idAreaMain="1"
                 )
  ) 
 AND idMedio="5" 
    OR ( idMedio="6" )
    )
AND News.state=1 
ORDER BY created DESC 
LIMIT 0, 20;

Comment: so? it's a query. But how do you know it's memory issue?

Comment: because when i checked the log, memory peaks for mySQL where red (i.ve updated the question, now the query is more legible)